# angular observable not fired in componnt

Tags: angular, rxjs

in my project I have BehaviorSubject in a service and a component that subscribes to it, in my component the subsription's callback  function is executed only the first time with an empty value, when I publish the data the callback is not executed; thia is my service:

```
  // tslint:disable: quotemark
  import { Injectable, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
  import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
  import { DatabaseReference, getDatabase,ref, onValue,remove,set,push, update } from 
  "firebase/database";
  import { ItemServiceInterface } from "../../item/models/ItemServiceInterface";
  import { UserModel } from "../models/userModel";
  import { ItemModelInterface } from "../../item/models/itemModelInterface";
  import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
  import { configs } from "src/app/configs/configs";
  import "firebase/firestore";
  import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
  import { credentials } from "src/app/configs/credentials";
  import { addDoc, collection, doc, getDoc, getDocs, getFirestore, query, setDoc } 
  from "firebase/firestore";
  import { Firestore } from "@google-cloud/firestore";

@Injectable({
providedIn: "root"
})
export class UsersService implements ItemServiceInterface, OnInit {
public itemsListReference: DatabaseReference;
items_list: Array<UserModel> = []
_items: BehaviorSubject<Array<UserModel>> = new BehaviorSubject([])
_loggedUser: BehaviorSubject<UserModel> = new BehaviorSubject(new UserModel)
loggedUser: Observable<UserModel> = this._loggedUser.asObservable()


readonly items: Observable<Array<UserModel>> = this._items.asObservable()
static loggedUser:UserModel
db: any
usersRef
constructor() {
//                                                        this.itemsListReference = 
ref(this.db)//,"/userProfile");
  this.loadDataAndPublish()
  const app = initializeApp(credentials.firebase)
  this.db = getFirestore(app)
  this.usersRef = collection(this.db,'users')
  this.items.subscribe(items=>{ // just to test it is called twice
    console.log("observing in service",items)
  })


}
categoriesService?: ItemServiceInterface;
suppliersService?: ItemServiceInterface;
paymentsService?: ItemServiceInterface;
itemsListRef: DatabaseReference;
reference='userProfile'
populateItems = async (UsersListSnapshot) => {
  this.items_list = [];
  UsersListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
    const user = new UserModel(undefined, snap.key).load(snap.data()).setKey(snap.id)
    this.items_list.push(user);

  });
  return this.items_list
}
ngOnInit(): void {
}

loadDataAndPublish() {
  const auth = getAuth();
  onAuthStateChanged(auth,async (user) => {
    const q = query(collection(this.db,"users"))
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
   const users =await  this.populateItems(querySnapshot)
   console.log("items to publish",users)
    this._items.next(users)

  });
}

async getItem(key: string) {
  const docSnap = await getDoc(this.usersRef)
   return new UserModel(docSnap.data())
}

FetchRole(level:number){
  return configs.accessLevel.filter(accesslevel=>accesslevel.value==level)[0]
}

getLoggedUser() {
  return this.loggedUser;
}

//
 callCloudPushUser(user:{}){
const functions = getFunctions()


const insertUser = httpsCallable(functions,'adminAddUserProfile')
return insertUser(user).then((msg)=>{
  console.log('insert use',msg)
}).catch((error)=>{
console.error(error);
});

}

setLoggedUser(user: ItemModelInterface) {
  console.log('setting user', user)
  this._loggedUser.next(new UserModel(user, user['uid']));
  UsersService.loggedUser= new UserModel(user, user['uid'])
  return this.loggedUser;
}

deleteItem(key: string) {

  const itemRef = ref(this.db,this.reference+key)
  return remove(itemRef)
  
}

getEmptyItem() {
  return new UserModel();
}

async  createItem(item: ItemModelInterface) {
  return  setDoc(doc(this.db,"users",item.key),item.serialize())
}

getEntitiesList(): DatabaseReference{
  return this.itemsListReference;
}

async  updateItem(item: ItemModelInterface) {
  return setDoc(doc(this.db,"users",item.key),item.serialize())
}
}
```

this the code in my component:

```
this.service._items.subscribe(items=> {
  console.log("observing items",items)// it is called only with items=[]
})
```

it should be nothing special, but it does not work, I have no clues at all, why it does not work

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the callback function you're sending to `onAuthStateChanged` has a `this` you're not expecting.

Try changing the callback from an anonymous function to a new `processOnAuthStateChanged` method, then replace `loadDataAndPublish` with

```js
loadDataAndPublish() {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const callback = this
    .processOnAuthStateChanged
    .bind(this);

  onAuthStateChanged(
    auth,
    callback
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks I followed your advice, the problem is still there , when I subscribe  to items inside the service, the callback function is fired twice, as expected, it gets an empty array and the array with the data, when I subscribe from the component, the callback is fired only once with the empty array

Comment: I noticed that the observers list of my observable pass from having 6 observer to one, how is it possible?

Comment: I don't know how you'd have six before! You *should* only have one, right?

Comment: yes it was my stupid  mistake, sorry

Answer (score 0):

from your code, we can notice the function "loadDataAndPublish" is the place you publish new data, but you didn't see the new data. so there may be two cases:

1. auth not pass. the function does not run at all. please make sure it does get the auth.
2. the second reason is "this" issue in your callback function. you can update the code to

```
  loadDataAndPublish() {
    const auth = getAuth();
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, this.authStateChangeHandler);
  }

authStateChangeHandler = async () => {
    const q = query(collection(this.db, "users"));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    const users = await this.populateItems(querySnapshot);
    console.log("items to publish", users);
    this._items.next(users);
  }
```

and by the way, in your components.
please subscribe to the "items" not the "_items".
_items should be private property in the service and you already have read-only "items" which is converted from the "_items".

```
this.service.items.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you

- rename `_items` to `items$`,
- replace your `items$` declaration and the `loadDataAndPublish` method with ...

```js
readonly items$: Observable<UserModel[]>;
readonly items_list$: Observable<UserModel[]> 

setItems$(): void {
  const authStateChangeObserver = new Subject();
  const db = this.db;
  this.items$ = concat(
    [],
    authStateChangeObserver.pipe(
      tap(x => console.log(1, x)),
      map(user => query(collection(
        db,
        "users"))
      ),
      tap(x => console.log(2, x)),
      switchMap(getDocs),
      tap(x => console.log(3, x)),
      switchMap(this.populateItems.bind(this)),
      tap(x => console.log(4, x)),
    )
  ).pipe(
    shareReplay(1)
  ); 

  getAuth().onAuthStateChanged(
    authStateChangeObserver
  ); 

  this.items_list$ = this.items$.pipe(
    map(UsersListSnapshot => UsersListSnapshot.map(
      snap => new UserModel(
        undefined,
        snap.key
      ).load(
        snap.data()
      ).setKey(snap.id)
    ),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
}
```

- change the constructor to call `setItems$` instead of `loadDataAndPublish`, and
- remove `items_list`

then I believe this will solve a number of issues.

First; No subscribing. You don't have to worry about cleanup.

Second: If I understand the documentation correctly, onAuthStateChanged is not a static method! I think this night be a big part of the issue.

Third: Instead of exposing a subject, you're only exposing readonly observables.

Fourth: No scope issues with `this`.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I solved was a configuration error on my code